# Disable pre-compilation in ASP.NET MVC 5 webjob project?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have a solution that includes an ASP.NET MVC 5 web application and three webjob projects.

I am using pre-compliation of the razor files for the web application (necessary!), but I have just noticed that when the solution builds for deployment, msbuild is running `aspnet_merge` four times, once for the web application and then once for each of the webjob projects.

Since there is no UI (no `.cshtml` files) for the webjob projects, there is no need to run `aspnet_merge` on those projects.

Is there a way to prevent `aspnet_merge` from running on those projects? Normally, it wouldn't matter too much, it would just be three warnings at build time and some extra time. But something happened this week and now `aspnet_merge` is failing on one of the webjob projects because it is saying that it can't find `Microsoft.Web.Infrastructure` version 1.0.0 at compile time, which is correct since the project uses version 2.0.0 and a binding redirect to ensure that all references map to version 2.0.0.

I really need to get past the error, and I figured disabling `aspnet_merge` on these webjob projects would be the best approach.

Comment: It's more than just `.cshtml` files - your `Global.asax` file still needs to be precompiled and managed by `aspnet_merge`, and it also checks for the "magic" directories like `App_Code`  and `App_Themes` - even if you aren't using them. Fortunately all that's gone in ASP.NET Core, so my suggestion to you is to bite-the-bullet and upgrade to ASP.NET Core.

Comment: _"a binding redirect"_ - is this redirect in your `web.config` or elsewhere?

Comment: I would like to "bite-the-bullet" and move up to .Net Core, but time does not permit it. I am working towards it by eliminating the .cshtml in the project but the volume of code and amount of work to do that is too much when there are customer requests to satisfy.

Comment: the binding redirect is in the app.config of the webjob project. The webjob project is a new style project with a Dependencies node rather than a references node in its project tree.